# CSS nth-last-child browser support

Tags: css, browser

Is anyone familiar with the :nth-last-child pseudo-selector?
I was surprised it isn't listed on caniuse.com.

So, what are your experiences in regards to IE support?
Would be cool to add color to long and boring lists of li's.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp

Comment: it supported on IE9+ versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
  <ul>
      <li>First Item</li>
      <li>Second Item</li>
      <li>Third Item</li>
      <li>Fourth Item</li>
      <li>Fifth Item</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  background: slategrey;
}
/* select the second-last item */
li:nth-last-child(2) {
  background: lightslategrey;
}
```

[image]

[See more details](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-child/)

[Mention in HTML5Please Selectors](http://html5please.com/#selectors)

Adding a list to HTML5Please Selector section for css, which mentions the availability of nth-last-child after IE8 sunset.

**Usage of selectivizr**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

- Just include this script in your page's  tag. If you're not
  already using a JavaScript library, you'll need to choose one from
  the table below.

[image]

Comment: but `:nth-last-child` doesn't support on IE8?

Comment: @KheemaPandey Yes see the updated link by alexK85. http://html5please.com/#selectors

Comment: Cool, thank you all for your insightful comments. And you, newTag. Bookmarking this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced CSS selectors supports almost all browsers but for IE: supports from IE9.

Check this : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 0):

An addition: If you want to use the selector on IE7 and IE8 you can use [Webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/). This is a polyfill javascript library that enables HTML5 and CSS3 selectors to older browsers (most of the time IE7 and IE8).It's easy to use and install.

Here is a link with a detailed description of how to use it: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-the-webshims-polyfill

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` `:nth-last-child` doesn't work on IE8. you can use a javascript library called `selectivizr` http://selectivizr.com/.

selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8.

you can make a zebra strippting using the `:nth-child`

```
ul li{ list-style-type:none; line-height:1.5em;}

li:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #eee;
}
```

HTML is like this..

```
 <ul>
    <li>ITem1 </li>
    <li>ITem2 </li>
    <li>ITem3 </li>
    <li>ITem4 </li>
    <li>ITem5 </li>
    <li>ITem6 </li>
  </ul>
```

Here is a working Demo. http://jsbin.com/yaculabe/1/edit

Comment: @user3322631 Does my solution is helpful for you?